# Split text file into two based on gender in a line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have to write a Shell script to split the `names.txt` file into two files `male_nominee.txt` and `female_nominee.txt` based on gender.

If file `male_nominee.txt` or `female_nominee.txt` already exists, then append the content otherwise we have to make the files.
`names.txt` has text like this:

```
23|Arjun|Male
24|Akshara|Female
17|Aman|Male
19|Simran|Female
```

I wrote the following script but something is not right:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
if [ -f male_nominee.txt ] 
then
     grep -n "Male" names.txt > male_nominee.txt
else
     mkdir -p male_nominee.txt
     grep -n "Male" names.txt > male_nominee.txt
fi
if [ -f female_nominee.txt ]
then 
    grep -n "Female" names.txt > female_nominee.txt
else
    mkdir -p female_nominee.txt
    grep -n "Female" names.txt > female_nominee.txt
fi
```

Comment: Making directories means you can't create files with the same name; that is unambiguously wrong.  The `>>` operator will append to an existing file and create a non-existing one.  That means you can use two `grep` commands (only) to do the job.

Comment: Also, you probably don't want `grep -n` but just `grep`. The `-n` would add linenumbers in the format `123:...` that were not there in the original file. And you also should change `"Male"`/`"Female"` to `'|Male$'`/`'|Female$'` to avoid false positives.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so if I write >> it will check for both conditions i.e it will append to existing file or create and then write if it doesn't exist??

Comment: @Socowi thanks for the tip..but won't the search be case sensitive. I am a beginner , so I am sorry if I missed something.
Will Male and male be considered same..?

Comment: Both `>>` and `>` will create the file if it doesn't exist. The difference is, if the file exists, then `>>` appends to the file while `>` overwrites the file.

Comment: @Socowi oh. Ok got it .Thanks.

Comment: @Socowi , thanks I got it to work.
Thanks for your help and patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `awk`:

```
awk -F'[|]' '$3 == "Male" { print >> "male_nominee.txt"}
             $3 == "Female" { print >> "female_nominee.txt" }' names.txt
```

Tell it that pipe is the column delimiter, and depending on the value of the third column, append the current line to the appropriate file (Just like in shell, `>>` redirection in `awk` will create the file if it doesn't already exist, and append to existing ones.)